# Stepping between spherical coords (OpenGL, C++, GLUT)

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have defined 2 points on the surface of a sphere using spherical coordinates.

```
// define end point positions
float theta_point_1 = (5/10.0)*M_PI;
float phi_point_1 = (5/10.0)*2*M_PI;
float x_point_1 = Radius * sin(theta_point_1) * cos(phi_point_1);
float y_point_1 = Radius * sin(theta_point_1) * sin(phi_point_1);
float z_point_1 = Radius * cos(theta_point_1);

float theta_point_2 = (7/10.0)*M_PI;
float phi_point_2 = (1/10.0)*2*M_PI;
float x_point_2 = Radius * sin(theta_point_2) * cos(phi_point_2);
float y_point_2 = Radius * sin(theta_point_2) * sin(phi_point_2);
float z_point_2 = Radius * cos(theta_point_2);


// draw end points
void end_points ()
{
    glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glPointSize(25.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(x_point_1,y_point_1,z_point_1);
    glVertex3f(x_point_2,y_point_2,z_point_2);
    glEnd();
}
```

To step between the two points, I do the following:

1. find the difference between theta_points_1,2 and phi_points_1,2
2. divide the differences by 'n' (yielding 's')
3. redraw 'n' times, while stepping up the theta and phi by 's' each time

In the following, I've defined the differences between my theta and phi values, divided them, and then redraw them.

```
// begining spherical coords
float theta_point_1_value=5;
float phi_point_1_value=5;

// ending sperical coords
float theta_point_2_value=7;
float phi_point_2_value=1;

// dividing the difference evenly
float step_points=30;
float step_theta = 2/step_points;
float step_phi = 4/step_points;

// step between spherical coordinates
void stepping_points ()
{
    glColor3f (1.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
    for (int i = 1; i < step_points; i++)
    {
        float theta = (theta_point_1_value/10.0)*M_PI;
        float phi = (phi_point_1_value/10.0)*2*M_PI;
        float x = Radius * sin(theta) * cos(phi);
        float y = Radius * sin(theta) * sin(phi);
        float z = Radius * cos(theta);  
        glPushMatrix();         
        glTranslatef(x,y,z);
        glutSolidSphere (0.05,10,10);
        glPopMatrix(); 
    }  
    glEnd();
}
```

Now I understand, this displays 30 solid spheres at the same position. Because I have NOT included 'step_theta' or 'step_phi' in any of the redraws.

And that is the root of my question. How do I employ 'step_theta' and 'step_phi' in my redraws?

What I want to do is say something like this at the top of my 'for' loop:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < step_points; i++)
    {
        float theta_point_1_value = (theta_point_1_value+step_theta);
        float phi_point_1_value = (phi_point_1_value+step_phi);

        float theta = (theta_point_1_value/10.0)*M_PI;
        float phi = (phi_point_1_value/10.0)*2*M_PI;
        float x = Radius * sin(theta) * cos(phi);
        float y = Radius * sin(theta) * sin(phi);
        float z = Radius * cos(theta);  
        glPushMatrix();         
        glTranslatef(x,y,z);
        glutSolidSphere (0.05,10,10);
        glPopMatrix(); 
    }
```

The above will redraw 30 solid spheres, but they don't show between my defined end points. It's pretty clear that either my math or syntax is screwy (or more than likely, both are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: What is the range of your loop variable, `i`? What do you want the range of your `step_theta` and `step_phi` to be?

When you declare a variable inside the loop, it goes out of scope and is destructed after every iteration. As such, only the value of `i` changes between your loop iterations.

Also: Consider using a vector/point class. `(x_point_1, y_point_1)` is not C++ :).

Comment: Thank you very much. aib. I really appreciate your help.  

I've simply replaced:  

    for (int i = 1; i < step_points; i++)  

with…  

    for (float phi_point_1_value = 5; phi_point_1_value > phi_point_2_value; phi_point_1_value-=step_phi)  

Of course this only steps properly along the latitude (phi). I'll continue digging to see how I can solve for theta as well. (Obviously I'm new to this - heheh).  Thank you again!.........................................also, ugh - trying to figure out how to leave a properly formatted comment as well :/  (sorry)

Comment: You can use the `,` operator to work with multiple variables in the `for` statement. But I was thinking more along the lines of using `i` inside the loop body (between `{` and `}`) to adjust theta/phi...

Comment: Wonderful - thank you!! :) I was able to work with multiple variables in the 'for' statement using ','. That being said, what would the benefit of employing 'i' inside the loop be instead? I'm certain more experience will help me figure that out. Also, I will be exploring the vector/point class as well. Thank you again. I deeply appreciate your time.

Comment: Well, the loop statement is more "crowded". You should simplify your code as much as possible. If something along the lines of `for (step = 0; step < step_points; ++step) { theta = theta_start + theta_step * step; }` is easier to read (and thus maintain) you should prefer it.

Comment: I myself prefer using an [aptly named standalone linear interpolation function](http://processing.org/reference/lerp_.html) for stuff like this.

Comment: Ahhh, ic ic. It's infinitely easier to read - heh. Thank you kindly - you've made this very clear for me. I will look further into the lerp() function as well - it looks to be very useful for interpolating between points, and very easy to manage/maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want consistent timing regardless of frame rate, you need to track the passage of time and use that to control how far you interpolate between the two points. Remember the start time and calculate the desired end time, then each frame, calculate `(float)(now-start)/(end-start)`. This will give you a value between 0.0 and 1.0. Multiply that value by the delta of each spherical coordinate and add their start angles and you'll get what angles you need to be at now.